# Run exe file on full screen mode game

Tags: c++, dll, vb6, dll-injection

My question would be complex ..

At first, the idea which I want to achieve is showing an executable file <.exe> (Say its name is Project1.exe) coded into VB6 in the flight simulator game full screen mode (from a specific path) by pressing on a specific menu item has been inserted into FS2004 - Microsoft Flight Simulator menu bar by C++ dll file inserted into (Modules) folder of the game [ I have achieved that part successfully as shown in below screenshot ]

[image: Created Menu by C++]

The game has a folder called (Modules) which includes dll files, which the process reads their codes ( I guess no need for dll injection here ), In below screenshot picture the game sent an error because it cannot read (A-Sample.dll) file which is empty from any codes ( just for getting the error ) - That means we don't need dll injection to show the executable file Project1.exe on top of the full screen mode game.

[image: Modules folder and DLLs files]

The question is : How can I code the A-Sample.dll in C++ to run Project1.exe on the top of the full screen mode ? - any codes or programmatic ideas ...

Comment: If the DLL is loaded in that directory, it seem that the flight simulator has a plugin mechanism. So you must look for a description on the format of such a plugin. There must exist a development kit for this, which may not neccessarily available and could be an internal thing as well. You might take a look here http://www.microsoft.com/Products/Games/FSInsider/developers/Pages/. There are links to development resources, so you may find something there.

Comment: Thanks @Devolus for such information, So. in that case, If the A-Sample.dll file has been coded to show the form on the top of full screen mode it will work without needing dll injection method .. Am I right ? -

Comment: Yes. Indications are that you are using a plugin system. How much freedom that system offers I can't say, so you must check out the developers kit.

Comment: Yea, It's really an amazing space of freedom to do whatever you want, I checked out the developers corner (By the way -Thanks for the link) but didn't find anything regarding showing windows applications on top of full screen mode .. When I press menu sub-item (Airport Codes), the menu item inserting dll file runs the VB6 executable file from a specific path (e.g. C:\AirlineCo\Project1.exe) it do it successfully, but when the program loaded, the flight simulator which on full screen mode minimizes to taskbar .So, any idea to show the program on top of the flight simulator without it minimizes?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help you there, as I don't know the simulator code. I used it many years ago, but just as a player. :)

Comment: Thanks Devolus for your kind trying to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DLL is loaded in that directory, it seem that the flight simulator has a plugin mechanism. So you must look for a description on the format of such a plugin. There must exist a development kit for this, which may not neccessarily available and could be an internal thing as well. You might take a look here http://microsoft.com/Products/Games/FSInsider/developers/Pages. There are links to development resources, so you may find something there